# What is this distribution name

Tags: distribution, cdf, exp

can someone name a distribution which has this CDF?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Strange formula. t on the left, x on the right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution), a.k.a. Generalized Extreme Value distribution Type-I.